# want to update dropdown in each row in the database using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my UI Screenshot. Highlighted is the Dropdown

[image: Highlighted is the Dropdown]

**What i want?**

As i Select any option in the Dropdown it should get updated for that particular row in Database using AJAX

Below are the Codes that i've written. I'm just a Beginner, please excuse if the code is not neat!!

*I'm using Codeigniter*

**Front End**

```
 <?php if( is_array( $fbrecords ) && count( $fbrecords ) > 0 ) 
foreach($fbrecords as $r) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->fullname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->mobile; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->message; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->jtime; ?></td>
        <td> <?php  $data=array(

'name'=>'status',
'row' => '12px',
'id' => 'status',
'selected'=>'none',
'class'=>'statusClass'

);
$data_status = array(
'none' => 'none',
'A&A' => 'Attended & Acted',
'YTA' => 'Yet to Attend',
);
echo form_dropdown($data, $data_status, set_value('status')); ?> </td>
```

**Ajax Code - I've added a Console.log to see weather next row dropdown is being selected or not**

```
$(document).ready(  function() {
$(".statusClass").change(function(event) {

//var dropDown = document.getElementById("status");
//var status =  dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
var status = $("select.statusClass").val();
console.log(status);
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/user_authentication/user_data_status_submit",
dataType: 'json',
data: {status:status},
success: function(data){
if (result)
{
alert("success");
}
}

});
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_data_status_submit(){

$data = array(

'status' => $this->input->post('status'),

);

//Either you can print value or you can send value to database
echo json_encode($data);
$this->login_database->feedback_update($data);

}
```

***Console Ouputs for the first 3 rows show the 1 row selection thrice - Below is the Screeshots of that  ***

[image: Shows the first row o/p thrice after selecting 2nd and 3rd row DropDown]

Comment: use var status = $(this).val();
console.log(status);

and check.

Comment: OMG!!! You're a Genius mahn!! Whole day i was going mad about this!! this was my first question in this portal and got the answer this soon. thanks mate!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the values of all select box. Instead of that you get the values which you are updating to obtain the result `this` keyword will use.

```
$(document).ready(  function() {
$(".statusClass").change(function(event) {
    var status = $(this).val();
```